# How to remove mask on parsing?

Tags: c#, wpf, parsing, datetime, format

I have a masked textbox for date:

```
<xctk:MaskedTextBox x:Name="txtDataNasc" Mask="##/##/####" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="27" TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="199" Margin="121,133,0,0" TextChanged="txtDataNasc_TextChanged"/>
```

And on that textbox `Text_Changed` property I parse it's value to DateTime:

```
_student.Student_birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataNasc.Text.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

But it's not a valid DateTime String. I tried:

```
stg.Replace("/", "-").Replace("#", "");
```

But it's still keeping the textMask. How do I remove the mask on parse?

The all thing on `TextChanged` looks like this:

```
string stg = txtDataNasc.Text.ToString();
stg.Replace("/", "-").Replace("#", "");
stg = stg + " 00:00:00";
_student.Student_birthDate = DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataNasc.Text.ToString(), "yyyy-MM-dd h:mm tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: Your `Mask` and your format does not match as far as I can see. Why don't you use just `MM/dd/yyyy` or `dd/MM/yyyy` (I don't know which one is right) instead? Why do you need `h:mm tt` part if your MaskedTextBox does **not** have it? You don't need to use this `stg` string at all **since you don't use it anywhere**. Also, these `Replace` methods returns a new string instance. They don't/can't modified the current instance since strings are immutable.

Comment: Just `DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataNasc.Text, "MM/dd/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` or `DateTime.ParseExact(txtDataNasc.Text, "dd/MM/yyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` (depends on which `##` is days or months) seems enough to use it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A mask is a mask and a value is a value. Two different things. Also your mask doesn't match the yyyy-MM-dd format so the `DateTime.ParseExact` method will always fail. The sample code you have posted doesn't make much sense. Try this:

```
private void txtDataNasc_TextChanged(object sender, TextChangedEventArgs e)
{
    string stg = txtDataNasc.Text;
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(stg))
    {
        stg += " 00:00:00";

        DateTime date = default(DateTime);
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(stg, "dd-MM-yyyy hh:mm:ss", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out date))
        {
            _student.Student_birthDate = date;
        }
    }
}
```

This will work if you put in 29-01-2017 in the TextBox. If you want to use another date format you should modify the format string that you pass to the `DateTime.TryParseExact` method as well as the value of the Mask property of the `MaskedTextBox`.

Also note that you won't be able to convert the string to a valid `DateTime` and set the Student_birthDate property until the full date has been typed into the `MaskedTextBox`.